# Add 6 months to column mydate if mydate is not nulll or blank and mydate>todaydate

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select 
    case 
       when Mydate is null then todaydate
       when Mydate = 0 then 99999999
       when Mydate > todaydate then convert(char(10), DATEADD(MONTH, 6, convert(DATE, convert(CHAR(10), Mydate,120))), 112)
       else 99999999
    end as exp
from 
    table
```

Mydate data is coming as 2021-01-20 so exp column is defaulting to 99999999 because of the -

Sample: mydate 2021-03-23 then exp 20210923

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

> Add 6 months to column mydate if mydate is not nulll or blank and mydate>todaydate

You seem to want:

```
(case when mydate > getdate()
      then dateadd(month, 6, mydate)
      else mydate
 end)
```

I'm not sure what your code snipped has to do with answering the question.